# Is there a better way to write a formula using VBA variables

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write the following formula in VBA for a conditional formatting statement:

```
r.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND($AYQ4<=D$3;$AYR4>=D$3)"
```

In VBA I have the following variables of data type long representing the various address parts:

- the column D: lCurrentColumn
- the column AYQ: lStartcolumn
- the column AYR: lEndcolumn
- the row 3: lHeadersRow
- the row 4: lCurrentRow

What is the best way to write the statement above using VBA variables instead of typing the row numbers and column names? Is there a better way than:

```
r.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND($" colnumtoletter(lStartColumn) &  lCurrentRow & "<=" & columntoletter(lCurrentColumn) & "$" & lHeadersRow & ",$" & lEndColumn & lCurrentRow & ">=" & lCurrentColumn & "$" & lHeadersRow" & ")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If r (or its first cell) refers to D4, you could use:

```
r.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(R[0]C" & lStartColumn & "<=R" & lHeadersRow & "C,R[0]C" & lEndColumn & ">=R" & lHeadersRow & "C)"
```

As a side note, make sure you select r before doing this since you are using relative referencing.

Comment: You mean that I should make sure to set r before I do this right? I don't think it matters which cell is selected.

Comment: No, I mean you should actually select it. If you don't you may get strange results, depending on your version of Excel - see MSKB here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895562/

Comment: Wow, interesting, thank you for the warning. Q1: Is it enough to add the line r.select before I apply the conditional formating? The article implies that more needs to be done, but I don't fully understand it: "When you want to apply conditional formatting to a cell, first select the cell that you want to use for the conditional formatting. Then, select the cell that you want to use for the formula. After you select this cell, modify the formula to suit your requirements.". Also, Q2: does it matter that r is not just one cell?

Comment: As long as the right sheet is active, yes, just select `r`. It doesn't matter if it's more than one cell.